# Java - Getting values from Property File

Tags: java

-- Scenario 1 --

This is my property file:

```
template.lo=rule A | template B
template.lo=rule B | template X
template.lo=rule C | template M
template.lo=rule D | template G
```

I dont think the above design is allowed since there's duplicate keys

-- Scenario 2 --

```
template.lo1=rule A | template B
template.lo2=rule B | template X
template.lo3=rule C | template M
template.lo4=rule D | template G
```

The above design is definitely allowed.

I want to retrieve values from Java, so I'll pass in the key to get the value. Normally, I'll use this way:

```
PropertyManager.getValue("template.lo1",null);
```

The problem is the key will keep on increasing, the above example got 4... in the future there might be 5 or 10.

So, my question is, how am I going to retrieve all the values?

If i know that there are 10 keys in total, I can use this way:

```
List <String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>();
     for(int i = 1; i<totalNumberOfKeys+1; i++{
     String value = (String) PropertyManager.getValue("template.lo"+i,null)
     valueList.add(value);
}
```

but the problem is I dont have any idea on the number of keys. I cannot pull all the values since there will be other keys which i dont want.

Any idea on this?

Comment: you could use a single property value and use a delimiter to split them. something like "template.lo=rule A | template B,rule B | template X,rule C | template M"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to get the properties until I got `null`:

```
public List<String> getPropertyValues(String prefix) {
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=1;;i++) {
        String value = (String) PropertyManager.getValue(prefix + i, null);
        if(value == null){
            break;
        }
        values.add(value);          
    }
    return values;
}
```

This assumes there are no *holes* in the property list (like: `template.lo1=.., template.lo3=...`)

Answer (score 3):

`jav.util.Properties` has [`propertyNames()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#propertyNames%28%29):

> Returns an enumeration of all the keys in this property list, including distinct keys in the default property list if a key of the same name has not already been found from the main properties list.

You can loop over them and take only those you need.

There is also [`stringPropertyNames()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#stringPropertyNames%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

[ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) is what I've used previously for properties files.

If you check out the API you should be able to find how to create a ResourceBundle for you file.
Then there is a `containsKey(String)` method that you could use as your loop condition.

So you would use something like the following:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = new ResourceBundle();
bundle.getBundle("My/File/Name");

List <String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>();

int i = 1;
String propertyKey = "template.lo" + i;
while( bundle.containsKey(propertyKey) ) {
    valueList.add((String) bundle.getObject(propertyKey));
    i++;
    propertyKey = "template.lo" + i;
}
```